# Javascript or jquery: Can you load a page and then call a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario:** You have  a script that users can place on their website and when they click on it, it redirects to my website then calls a function only after they have successfully been redirected to my website and the function is part of my website, so there shouldn't be any problem with the same origin security policy.

So is the scenario possible?

**EDIT**

Ok now that I know that it can be done, I run into a pickle doing this.

```
function main(){
$(document).ready(function($){
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/michael';
theclient.chat();

});
}
```

I want theclient.chat() to be called after example.com/michael is loaded but it's not working.

**UPDATE 2**

```
function main(){
window.location.href = 'http://www.reflap.com/michaelnana';

$(document).ready(function(){
theclient.chat();

});

}
```

So will this work?

Comment: Yes of course. When the browser loads your page, it's your page, just as if the user had clicked on a simple link (which, really, is what you're describing).

Comment: I think the key is to call a JS function on the new site

Answer (score 2):

You have to call that function on your own site in the following block:

Source page:

```
function main(){
    window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/michael';
}
```

Target page (`http://www.example.com/michael`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    theclient.chat();
});
```

To be clear: this will be called, if you type the URL of the page too and not only after a redirect.

You should add a URL parameter when you do the redirect, if you want to call it only after a redirect.

UPDATE:
You cannot call a function on the original page, after the redirect has been done.

Comment: Thanks for the initial answer Balint. I did update the question because I think you'll be able to give me a better answer based on the update.

Comment: The `theclient.chat();` row is not executed simply because you are already redirected (so the old page is unloaded)

Comment: Yeah but theclient.chat() is not a function of the old page. It's a function of example.com . Do you see what I mean?

Comment: That is not possible, you need to call that in the ready block of the new page

Comment: See update (by the way putting the document ready in another function is not really useful)

Comment: So in your update the ready block is not in the function main right?

Comment: That is a minor fix, but the key thing is that you cannot call a JS function on another page. You have to call that function in the `ready` block of the _new_ page! That is why I've added 2 code blocks: 1st is redirecting and 2nd is on the target page and doing the JS call.

Comment: Ohh maybe I understand what you mean more now. The update 2 won't work still because I'm still not in the target page. Is that right? So you're saying that $(document).ready(function(){
    theclient.chat();
});   should be added in the code of the test.php on the main page right?

Comment: In your question, nothing is calling your `main()` function after the page is loaded. Use @BalintBako's target page code.

Comment: There is a call to the main, the snippet I have wasn't the whole code of the page.

Comment: `The update 2 won't work still because I'm still not in the target page. Is that right?` That is correct.
And if `test.php`is the target of the redirect, then `So you're saying that $(document).ready(function(){ theclient.chat(); }); should be added in the code of the test.php on the main page right? ` this is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

On your target page, if you include the jQuery library, use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
theclient.chat();
});
```

The `ready()` method makes sure the page (`http://www.reflap.com/michaelnana`) is rendered before running your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I've included 3 sample files that should serve as a skeleton for what you're trying to do.

www.external-site.com/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>3rd Party Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="http://www.example.com/michael/embed.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

www.example.com/michael/embed.js

```
// load jQuery, keep it in our scope
//   I'll not explain how this works but if you're making an embed
//   script for other sites, you must make sure to encapsulate all
//   your dependencies such as jQuery.
loadDependencies(function($) {
  // document onload
  $(function() {
    // create a button that redirects to example.com/michael
    var button = $('<a>').text('click me').click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/micahel';
    });

    // insert that button after this script tag
    var src = 'http://www.example.com/michael/embjed.js';
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').after(button);
  });
});
```

www.example.com/michael/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="theClient.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        // all visitors to this page will trigger this call, not just
        //   the ones who came from the script embed. If you want to
        //   differentiate I'd recommened adding a query paremeter to
        //   the redirect and reading it there.
        theClient.chat();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably mean `embed.js` not `embjed.js`